# EventSourceHttpClient never exits

Tags: php, symfony, server-sent-events, philips-hue

I'm trying to create some stuff on my Philips-Hue installation, using Symfony.
I'm able to control my lights, get motion sensor,... But all is working with GET requests. This is a very bad idea ;)

API provided by Philips comes with Events endpoint, as described here : [Core-concepts of meethue](https://developers.meethue.com/develop/hue-api-v2/core-concepts/#events)

So, I tried to use the "[Consuming Server Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#consuming-server-sent-events)" capability of Symfony in my application.

I do not understand how to use it? I tried to find more information, but this is always regarding sending information. I want to consume informations.
I tried to create some route, but the connect function does not end (I assume this is the normal way). So how to use the "$source" created by the call?

During my searches, I noticed that, if I enter one bad key, I get an error (Full HTML response), but this does not throw any Exception on the connect function. For me, as written line 112 of [source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpClient/EventSourceHttpClient.php), it should be.

For example, when using curl call:

```
curl --insecure -N -H 'hue-application-key: ThisIsAVeryBadKey' -H 'Accept: text/event-stream' https://ip-bridge/eventstream/clip/v2
```

I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>hue personal wireless lighting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="philips-header">
      <img src="/philips-blue.png" class="philips-logo" alt="Philips" />
    </div>
    <div class="header">
      <img class="header-logo" src="/hue-logo.png" alt="hue personal wireless lighting" />

      <img src="/hue-color-line.png" class="colorline" />

    </div>
    <div class="error">Oops, there appears to be no lighting here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I use a good key, I have the following:

```
:hi

id: 1639957108:0
data: [{"creationtime":"2021-12-19T23:38:28Z","data":[{"id":"YYYY","id_v1":"/sensors/30","owner":{"rid":"XXXXX","rtype":"device"},"temperature":{"temperature":19.059999465942383,"temperature_valid":true},"type":"temperature"}],"id":"ZZZZZ","type":"update"}]
```

Regards,